# Display Data using table cells and not divs

Tags: reactjs

I have data from JSON data (21 items) displayed as rows  in reactjs. After every 3rd item I would make it drop to the next line, using the code as below.

```
<div>{this.props.linkInfo.label}</div>
{(this.props.indexNbr+1) % 3 === 0?  <div style={clearBothStyle}> </div>  : null}
```

Now the requirement has changed and I have to display it using table cells so I used this code

```
<td>{this.props.linkInfo.label}</td>
{(this.props.indexNbr+1) % 3 === 0 ?  </tr><tr>  : null}
```

so after every 3 cells it would start a new row but I get a compilation error since in jsx `</tr><tr>` is not considered a valid jsx (close tag --> open tag). Is there a workaround for this? Is there a way to place non-uniform html in JSX?

Comment: sorry.. The HTML code is not displaying in the message above... Here is what I used:
 {this.props.linkInfo.label} {(this.props.indexNbr+1) % 7 === 0 ? </tr><tr> : null}

Comment: Just edit the question and correct the mistake.

Comment: @Faridsk https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I have tried editing the question to place just this simple HTML <div style={{clear:both}}></div> '</tr><tr>' but it just won't display.

Comment: You have to use **backticks** or **indentation** to format code. Simple quotes don't mark the content as code.

Comment: *"Is there a workaround for this?"* The proper way would be to change the structure of your data so that you can easily create rows from that (i.e. you prepare the data to be an array of row data). But without a complete example its difficult to help.

Comment: NOt sure what you mean by change the data structure. FIrstly data is not under my control.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by computing the number of rows of your table:

```js
let rows = Math.ceil(data.length / 3);
```

Then you can loop from 0 to rows:

```js
Array.from(Array(rows).keys()).map(i => (
  <tr>
    <td>{this.props.linkInfos[i].label}</td>
    <td>{this.props.linkInfos[i + 1].label}</td>
    <td>{this.props.linkInfos[i + 2].label}</td>
  </tr>
))
```